# How to use docker postgres as base image in Dockerfile?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, server, docker-multi-stage-build

I need to run a golang web server with postgres.
I wanted to put everything into one Docker image but don't know how to run database in the background.

**Dockerfile**

```
# Build Backend
FROM golang:1.16.3-alpine3.13 AS server-builder
WORKDIR /go/src
COPY backend .
RUN go build -o server .

FROM postgres:13.2-alpine
WORKDIR /wol-server
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD root
ENV POSTGRES_USER root
ENV POSTGRES_DB root
COPY --from=server-builder /go/src/ /wol-server/
COPY ./docker_postgres_init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker_postgres_init.sql
CMD ["./server"]
```

If I run `server` this way, database won't start, I tried a few different things but could not get it working.

FYI, here are some file of the official postgres docker image:

- [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/Dockerfile)
- [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Comment: This is not the recommended way. What you have is a multi stage build, it will only generate one image. What you need is using `docker-compose` to orchestrate multiple containers

Comment: What @TarunLalwani said is correct. To expand a bit ... the point of containerisation is to make each service a container, not to bundle multiple services into a single container. If you were looking to add some functionality or postgres or to extend postgres in some way then perhaps you would want to build that on top of a postgres image. But you say you are looking to run a golang server *with* postgres - so you should run a postgres container to supply your postgres DB and a golang container to run the golang server code.

Comment: you can have Postgres in different container and connect to it from golang container
like this: https://github.com/karlkeefer/pngr
so you will have a multi services architecture